# is there any function like string.isnullorempty() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, undefined

I always `(thing != undefined || thing != null)?...:...;` check. Is there any method will return bool after this check in javascript or jquery ?

And how would you add this check in jquery as a function?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
if (thing)
{
   //your code
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: :) this is really very easy isn't it :D

Comment: Be careful - this string and maybe a few others will fail that check: `"0"`.

Comment: He didnt ask for "0" and "false", but undefined or null.

Comment: @Joel: Wrong.  **All** non-empty strings are truthy.

Comment: @SLaks But only when no comparison is involved, so `if("0")` will be true but `if("0" == true)` won't, since type conversion took place.

Comment: This is unlike php, where "0" evaluates to false.

Answer (score 25):

In Javascript, the values `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and `false` are all "falsy" and will fail a conditional.
All other values are "truthy" and will pass a conditional.

Therefore, you can simply write  `thing ? ... : ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  function SringisEmpty(str) {
        str=str.trim();
        return (!str || 0 === str.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others here have mentioned, several things evaluate as "falsy" that you might not want to (such as empty strings or zero). The simplest way I've found in JavaScript to check for both `null` and `undefined` in one statement is:

```
thing != null
```

This is using type coercion (double equals instead of triple equals), so undefined values are coerced to `null` here, while empty strings, zero, etc. do not.